Do "basal" clades tend to be more similar than "derived" clades to their common ancestor?
I often hear certain clades described as "basal", "lower", or "less evolved", or "less recently diverging", and others described as "derived", "higher", "more evolved", "more recently diverging". These "basal" clades seem to be ones with few species compared to their sister clades. For example, within Gymnosperms, I've often heard ginkos and cycads described as being "ancient" plants. Sometimes the differences between more and less recently diverging clades are used to make arguments about broad evolutionary trends within a group (e.g., Ma et al. 2018).
However, as Krell and Cranston (2004) point out, which clade appears to one side of a phylogenetic tree is based on the arbitrary rotation of nodes, and they argue that therefore "basal" and "derived" are imprecise terms. Which clade is more or less recently diverging seems to me to be less arbitrary, but I still do not understand why it would serve as a measure of how primitive a clade is.
My question is, do the species in basal clades / less recently diverging clades tend to be more similar (molecularly or morphologically) than their sister clades to the common ancestor of the two? If so, why does similarity with the common ancestor correspond to less or less recent divergence within the clade?

From Forest et al. (2018)

I think there's a risk of tautology here; you're right, the drawing/ordering of a tree is not meaningful. But, if we label "basal" to be one that is most similar (perhaps superficially) to an inferred ancestral state, then of course basal is more similar to ancestral.

@BryanKrause I think you're right overall, but this is also a pretty common way of talking about taxonomy! I think it is worth sussing out whether this highly subjective but very common way of thinking about taxonomies does have any empirical validity. I bet it does!

@MaximilianPress Yeah, I think the "molecular" question is a more interesting and is non-tautological if "basal" is determined by (typically gross) morphology. The tautology comes up if your assessment and categorization use the same criteria.
